# Where should my SessionVar object be?

Tags: session, scala, lift

Programming in `Lift` (`Scala`) is really stressful, both of them have very scarse documentation, and the few you can find is incomplete and misleading.

Well, what I'm trying to do is to store a simple string in a `SessionVar`. So, one snippet will fill the value of this string using a form and in another snippet I'm gonna show the string in session (or its default value).

What I have so far is:

The `SessionVar` object:

```
// the SessionVar will contain a String with "Anonymous" as default value.
object myUser extends SessionVar[String]("Anonymous")
```

Snippet where I fill the string:

```
object Login extends LiftScreen {

  val name = field("Name: ", "")

  def finish() {
    // set the SessionVar string with the string entered
    myUser.set(name)
    S.notice("Your name is: "+name)
  }
}
```

Snippet where I show the string (another snippet):

```
// show the string in SessionVar
"Your name: " + myUser.is
...
```

`MyUser` is the object I'm saving in session. The big question is: **where do I keep my `MyUser` object**? I tried in the `Boot.scala` and in the two snippets, but I keep getting this error: `not found: value myUser`.

Where should I keep it? How should I import it? How can I make it work?

Comment: i don't know lift much but why not create a sessionvars.scala (or call it anything) and put definitions like myuser into it. afterall, it should just be in the classpath!

Comment: IMHO, you should learn some Scala basic first (for example, what `object myUser` means). Lift uses a lot of advanced Scala technique, which is not easy to understand without knowledge to basic Scala construct.

Comment: Don't know about Lift, but there is quite a lot of documentation on Scala. E.g. http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/ http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/

Comment: While Lift uses advance techniques, you can still get a lot done not really knowing "how" Lift handles things. And the lift community is always willing to answer any scala question if it will help understand how to do things in lift.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can place your SessionVar on the same "file" as your LiftScreen, but outside the object definition.

Something like this:

```
package com.code.snippet
import ...

object myUser extends SessionVar[String]("Anonymous")
object Login extends LiftScreen {

  val name = field("Name: ", "")

  def finish() {
    // set the SessionVar string with the string entered
    myUser.set(name)
    S.notice("Your name is: "+name)
  }
}
```

Now, on your other snippet, assuming you have it on a different file (Which I think it is as you are using LiftScreen, but if you were using a regular snippet class you could have more than one method rendering parts of the UI.
On this other file, you do need to import the object.

```
package com.code.snippet
import com.code.snippet.myUser
class MySnippet {
  render ={
    "#message" #> "Your name: " + myUser.is
  }  
}
```

You can also do it like this:

```
package com.code
package snippet
// notice the package split into two lines, making the import shorter.
import myUser
class MySnippet {
  render ={
    "#message" #> "Your name: " + myUser.is
  }  
}
```